# C++ Output list of objects with loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, object

Lets say I have an bunch of objects called Customer1 - Customer4

I want to be able to list these objects with a for loop so that I can display their details one after the other.
Here are the constructors I've used to make these objects:

```
Customers *Customer1 = new Customers("Eric Eddinger", "713 Pleasant Street, Crown Point, SA 2304", "83885445","Mr");
Customers *Customer2 = new Customers("Jackson Jean", "2311 Mill Road, Irwin, SA 3363", "8665421","Mr");
Customers *Customer3 = new Customers("Maye Min", "5 Evergreen Lane, Wisconsin, WA 8232", "77854126","Mrs");
Customers *Customer4 = new Customers("Ramon Rolfes", "689 River Road, Bensalem, SA 1239", "87226474","Mr");
```

What is the best way to output all of these objects with a single loop? Should I be adding all of these objects to an array? If so how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to assign an array of `Customer` and then iterate over it:

```
#include <iostream>

class Customer
{
public:
    std::string m_name, m_address, m_num, m_title;

    Customer(std::string name, std::string address, std::string num, std::string title) :
        m_name(name), m_address(address), m_num(num), m_title(title)
    {}
};

int main() {
    Customer customers[] = {
        Customer("Eric Eddinger", "713 Pleasant Street, Crown Point, SA 2304", "83885445", "Mr"),
        Customer("Jackson Jean", "2311 Mill Road, Irwin, SA 3363", "8665421", "Mr"),
        Customer("Maye Min", "5 Evergreen Lane, Wisconsin, WA 8232", "77854126", "Mrs"),
        Customer("Ramon Rolfes", "689 River Road, Bensalem, SA 1239", "87226474", "Mr")
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        std::cout   << "Name: " << customers[i].m_name
                    << " Address: " << customers[i].m_address
                    << " Num: " << customers[i].m_num
                    << " Title: " << customers[i].m_title << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need your objects stored in an array, otherwise you cannot use the proposed loop-approach.

```
// create the array
Customers* array[SIZE];

// put the object pointers there
array[0] = new Customers(...);
array[1] = new Customers(...);
...
```

Comment: Ok, so how would I go about adding my objects to an array? I assume I should be using pointers, beyond that im not so sure about how to implement it.

Comment: See my update. The example there is not ideal, its main purpose is to show you how to create such an array and how to put the object pointers there.